# Autoselect destination folder in DownThemAll 2

Tags: firefox, automation, download-manager

I read somewhere that you could set up filters in DownThemAll 2 Firefox extension, so that some files would be automatically sent to folder A, and other files to folder B. I've been poking around in the settings and I just can't find out how.

Just to be clear, I'm looking for a way to have all .mp3 be saved to the *Music* folder, and all .doc be saved to the *Documents* folder without having to select the right folders every time (only with more customization, of course). I used to achieve this with another extension (which I can't remember the name), but it doesn't support Firefox 4 yet.

Comment: DTA's developer is quite helpful. info@downthemall.net